# Ипнут не всегда передает значение в стейт

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть два инпута, которые находятся в форме:

```
  <label className='lable box'>
    Тяжесть
    <input
      name='heaviness'
      type='number'
      className='form__input input'
      onChange={handleChange}
    //required
    ></input>
  </label>
  <label className='lable box'>
    Вероятность
    <input
      name='probability'
      type='number'
      className='form__input input'
      onChange={handleChange}
    //required
    ></input>
  </label>
```

Функция обработки:

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState({});

const handleChange = (evt) => {
const { name, value } = evt.target;
setInputValue({
  ...inputValue,
  [name]: value,
});

const clear = () => {
  setInputValue({ probability: '', heaviness: '' });
  document.querySelector('.form').reset(); 
};
```

После очистки формы (метод формы reset()) значения инпута не всегда с первого раза передаются в стейт. Только после ввода второго символа стейт меняется.

Функция clear вызывается кнопкой очистки формы

```
<input
  type='reset'
  className='button reset'
  onClick={clear}
></input>
```

Comment: Что такое `inputValue` и где `reset()`? Добавьте в вопрос больше подробностей. И как вы проверяете, что стейт меняется?

Comment: Добавил информацию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, установим начальное состояние компонента как `{ probability: "", heaviness: "" }`

React должен контролировать элементы, для этого каждому input ставим значение value из стейта `value={inputValue.heaviness}` и `{inputValue.probability}`

Для доступа к предыдущему состоянию, в сетер передаем не значение, а функцию, где аргументом функции будет как раз "текущее состояние"

Так же в React, необходимо полностью избавляться от селекторов вида `document.get*` или `document.query*` - такие селекторы могут приводить к непредсказуемым последствиям

Ниже, ваш исправленный компонет, который реагирует на изменение значений ввода, а так же на кнопку сброса введенных значений.

```
const Inputs = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState({
    probability: "",
    heaviness: ""
  });

  const handleChange = (evt) => {
    setInputValue((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value
    }));
  };

  const clear = () => {
    setInputValue({ probability: "", heaviness: "" });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <label className="lable box">
        Тяжесть
        <input
          name="heaviness"
          type="number"
          className="form__input input"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={inputValue.heaviness}
          //required
        />
      </label>
      <label className="lable box">
        Вероятность
        <input
          name="probability"
          type="number"
          className="form__input input"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={inputValue.probability}
          //required
        />
      </label>
      <input type="reset" className="button reset" onClick={clear}></input>
    </>
  );
};
```

[Работающий пример в посочнице](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-roentgen-vddp4f?file=/src/App.js)